# TDD in Python: dependency injection for functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have recently been on a TDD course, and I've been trying to put the learnings into practice. I have been working on code to process some json documents, which involves functions that do a bit of processing, then call other functions to do parts of the work.

So, within a class, function 1 calls function 2, which then goes on to call function 3 etc. I have been using dependency injection to mock function 2 so I can make assertions about how function 2 was called by function 1. This involves passing in the mock as a parameter to function 1, which works fine when developing the functions in isolation. However, when I want to run the code for real and string all the independently tested functions together I'm running into problems. I can't seem to get it to work when I want to pass my actual function in. The below code does not work, but would hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
class myclass:

   def function1(self, number, injected_function=function2):
        number = number + 1
        injected_function(number)

   def function2(self, number):
        number = number + 2
        print(number)

instantiated_class = myclass()
instantiated_class.function1(1)
```

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
class myclass:

   def function1(self, number):
        number = number + 1
        self.function2(number)

   def function2(self, number):
        number = number + 2
        print(number)

instantiated_class = myclass()
instantiated_class.function1(1)
```

But then obviously it makes it more difficult to test how function 2 was called. I know that `unittest.mock.patch` can be used in this scenario, but is that really the solution to all of this? It feels like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong - have I got the approach wrong with this TDD stuff!?

Comment: How is it not working? Is there any error output?

Comment: @MrJLP If you try and run the code in the first block, you will see the type of error. I'm worried that I'm just using the wrong type of design to acheive what I want to do - which is have the option of inserting a mock function in during testing, otherwise just use a default function

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you add to the question what error you're getting.

Running your code with Python 3.5 it gives me `NameError: name 'function2' is not defined`.

The problem is that at `function1` definition time `function2` is not defined yet. Declaring it before `function1` will solve this:

```
class myclass:

   def function2(self, number):
        number = number + 2
        print(number)

   def function1(self, number, injected_function=function2):
        number = number + 1
        injected_function(number)
```

This won't fix everything yet. What is tricky here is that you are referencing `function2` directly and not through `myclass`, so it won't be bound to the class when you call `injected_function(number)`. This means that parameter `self` won't be automatically provided to it, so `function2` will "see" the argument `number` you passed as `self` and then it will complain that it did not receive it's second argument `number`.

Your can solve this by calling `injected_function(self, number)` but this just have a potential for more trouble. Instead you can do something like this:

```
class myclass:
   def function1(self, number, injected_function=None):
        if injected_function is None:
            injected_function = self.function2
        number = number + 1
        injected_function(number)

   def function2(self, number):
        number = number + 2
        print(number)
```

This will work because you're are using a reference to `function2` that will be found inside `self`. So it is not needed at definition time and parameter `self` will be bound to the method call. At the same time, you won't have a problem supplying functions that aren't methods (ones that don't take a `self` parameter).

You could also just go and use the [injectable](https://github.com/allrod5/injectable) package. I maintain this lib for dependency injection.